# Level Conversion RGB LED Strip Noise Resistor (3.3 to 5)

Tags: level-shifting, ws2812b

I recently prototyped my circuit on a breadboard that controls a WS2812b RGB LED Strip.

The PDIP (breadboard friendly) ATMEGA644 uses 5V logic while TQFP uses 3.3V logic.

The LED strip specifies a resistance of 680 ohms to the data line of the strip to reduce noise.

The LED Strip does not operate correctly with 3.3V logic so I created a level converter.

My question: Should I include the 680 ohm resistance at the output of a level conversion circuit on the TQFP shown in the one below or should I neglect it or do something else?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is recommended, leave it in, or at least leave space for it.

The effects of the level translator may be enough to reduce the noise already, but it is better to have it and short it out later, than not have it and have to redo your board / wiring.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about not populating it. I'll do that.